# Divide int's and round up in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have 2 int's. How do I divide one by the other and then round up afterwards?

Comment: It's a very basic question, but it is legitimate; integer division doesn't always behave the way one would expect.

Comment: I know it sounds pretty lame but I struggle with the different objective-c data types, spoiled by the automatic casting you can do in .net

Answer (score 205, accepted):

If your ints are `A` and `B` and you want to have ceil(A/B) just calculate `(A+B-1)/B`.

Comment: I've seen it done this way many times. It's a good pattern to remember.

Comment: I dont think this works in all cases. (6 + 2 - 1) / 2 = 3.5, which because they are ints will be 3, that is not rounded up like the question asks, answer in that case should be 4.

Comment: @odyth: 6 divided by 2 is 3.

Comment: Your not dividing 6 and 2 though because you have to add them and subtract 1. So (6+2-1)/2 => (8-1)/2 => 7/2 = 3.5

Comment: @odyth: in integer arithmetics 3.5 is 3. and of course OP only wants rounding if needed — what isn't the case for 6/2 = 3 = (6 + 2 - 1) / 2  => True

Comment: I see what you're doing here.  Mathematically, the `+B-1` is similar to `+ ((float)B - 0.000001f)`.  You're basically increasing the numerator by all-but-B so that A/B whole-division still rounds down to the same quotient, but any A/B that would produce a remainder instead gives your the next-higher quotient.  Math!

Answer (score 37):

What about:

```
float A,B; // this variables have to be floats!
int result = floor(A/B); // rounded down
int result = ceil(A/B); // rounded up
```

Comment: Doesn't work for two ints, surely? Because the division will return an int result. But for two floats, converting to int (which is what I needed just now), this is correct.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that A and B have to be float! saved me

Answer (score 4):

```
-(NSInteger)divideAndRoundUp:(NSInteger)a with:(NSInteger)b
{
  if( a % b != 0 )
  {
    return a / b + 1;
  }
  return a / b;
}
```

Comment: since bools are still 0/1 in this language, you can just have:
`return a / b + (a % b != 0)`

Comment: Note that although this case is fine, BOOLs aren't necessarily 1 and 0. They are "0" and "not 0"

Comment: @Howard's solution may be more efficient & mathematically simpler, but I like this soltion more.  The intent and methodology is clearer to those of us programmers who think in terms of conditions and branching calculations, not algebraic equivalence. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

As in C, you can cast both to float and then round the result using a rounding function that takes a float as input.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;

float result = (float)a / (float)b;

int rounded = (int)(result+0.5f);
i
```

Comment: No need to cast to float - there are simpler and easier integer-only solutions - see @Howard's answer for example

Comment: Good point--I missed the "round up" part.  Howard's is a very elegant solution +1

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for 
2.1 roundup> 3

```
double row = _datas.count / 3;
double rounded = ceil(_datas.count / 3);
if(row > rounded){
    row += 1;
}else{

}
```